# android different position of text view on two devices

Tags: android

in my android app i have got an custom table list view.
there is an textview in the first row:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Seperator"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Seperator"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
```

i hide textView2 and the another view (Separator)
and move the textView up:

```
textView2.setAlpha(0);
Seperator.setAlpha(0);

parameter = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
parameter.setMargins(parameter.leftMargin,parameter.topMargin - 28, parameter.rightMargin, parameter.bottomMargin);

textView.setLayoutParams(parameter);
```

on my Samsung S4 API 21 it looks good:

[image]

but on my sony experia (api 18) it has a different position:

[image]

Where can be my mistake?

Comment: Move margines to dimensions file dimen.xml file and stop recalculating params of the textview.

Comment: **UPDATE** the margin-top from text to the green header is smaller than the margin-top of my samsung s4. i would like to set the textview vertical center.

Comment: @ Solanki. this margin-top value is only valid for the first row. the other rows should use the values of the xml. file

Comment: put your complete xml code and class files

Comment: sry, but which information do you need more? this code part should be enough, isn't it?

Comment: try to set the margins in xml rather than programatically

Answer (score 0):

> Becoz of you hardcoded textview size. you need to define in different dimens folder.just like

```
values-sw300dp-dimens.xml
values-sw480dp-dimens.xml
values-sw600dp-dimens.xml
values-sw800dp-dimens.xml
```

Comment: and which value i have to set in this xml. files?

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found my solution:

```
textView2.setAlpha(0);
Seperator.setAlpha(0);

parameter = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
parameter.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
textView.setLayoutParams(parameter);
```